# How can i make in xamarin that i will click on the smartphone and it will display the results on winforms?

Tags: c#, android, winforms, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I created in visual studio 2013 a new android application by xamarin.
The default project is making that when I click by touching my phone screen it will count on my phone the number of clicks I did.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate {
                button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

But I wonder if I can make that when I click on the screen of my phone it will show the number of clicks like now on the phone screen but also to display the number of clicks on a winforms designer ?

I know xamarin doesn't have winforms but maybe to connect to another winforms project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is either use a webservice or - that is the tricky way - communicate through a bluetooth connection. There is nothing build in that does what you want.